# Hive External table-CSV File- Header row

Tags: hive

Below is the hive table i have created:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Activity (
  column1 type, </br>
  column2 type
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/exttable/';
```

In my HDFS location /exttable, i have lot of CSV files and each CSV file also contain the header row. When i am doing select queries, the result contains the header row as well.

Is there any way in HIVE where we can ignore the header row or first line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row/15753145#15753145). Basically same answer there as here with some more suggestions. @kgu87's solution works too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip CSV header in Hive External Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/how-to-skip-csv-header-in-hive-external-table)

Answer (score 27):

you can now skip the header count in hive 0.13.0.

```
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: Note that this can be done to an existing table as well using ALTER TABLE.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableProperties

Answer (score 25):

If you are using Hive version 0.13.0 or higher you can specify "skip.header.line.count"="1" in your table properties to remove the header.

For detailed information on the patch see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5795

Answer (score 7):

Lets say you want to load csv file like below located at  `/home/test/que.csv`

```
1,TAP (PORTUGAL),AIRLINE
2,ANSA INTERNATIONAL,AUTO RENTAL
3,CARLTON HOTELS,HOTEL-MOTEL
```

Now, we need to create a location in HDFS that holds this data.

`hadoop fs -put  /home/test/que.csv /user/mcc`

Next step is to create a table. There are two types of them to choose from. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038414/difference-between-hive-internal-tables-and-external-tables/37192041#answer-21452633) for choosing one.

> Example for External Table.

```
create external table industry_ 
(
MCC string ,
MCC_Name string,
MCC_Group string
)       
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/mcc/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Note: When accessed via Spark SQL, the header row of the CSV will be shown as a data row.
Tested on: spark version 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

There is not. However, you can pre-process your files to skip the first row before loading into HDFS -

```
tail -n +2 withfirstrow.csv > withoutfirstrow.csv
```

Alternatively, you can build it into where clause in HIVE to ignore the first row.

Comment: How do you write a where clause in HIVE to ignore the first row?

Comment: If the data contains header row, then you can use where col <> 'header column name' in HQL, assuming the data itself does not contain that value. A better option for Hive 0.13.0 or higher would be to use skip.header.line.count when defining the table.

Comment: I used the hive tblproperties `("skip.header.line.count"="1");` property. But I am still able to see the header in hdfs table location. How can i remove the header line from being inserted into hdfs

Answer (score 0):

If your hive version doesn't support tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1"), you can use below unix command to ignore the first line (column header) and then put it in HDFS.

```
 sed -n '2,$p' File_with_header.csv > File_with_No_header.csv
```

Answer (score -2):

To remove the header from the csv file in place use:

```
sed -i 1d filename.csv
```