# Delete column in hive table

Tags: hiveql

I am working with hive version 0.9 and I need delete columns of a hive table. I have searched in several manuals of hive commands but I only I have found commands to version 0.14. Is possible to delete a column of a hive table in hive version 0.9? What is the command? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

We can’t  simply drop a table column from a hive table using the below statement like sql.

ALTER TABLE tbl_name drop column column_name ---- it will not work.

So there is a shortcut to drop columns from a hive table.

Let’s say we have a hive table.

From this table I want to drop the column Dob. You can use the ALTER TABLE REPLACE statement to drop a column.

```
ALTER TABLE test_tbl REPLACE COLUMNS(ID STRING,NAME STRING,AGE STRING);   you have to give the column names which you want to keep in the table
```

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan  What is the correct workaround?   Please answer the question as you've left later people having no idea how to do what the original question asks.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a drop column or delete column in Hive.

A SELECT statement can take regex-based column specification in Hive releases prior to 0.13.0, or in 0.13.0 and later releases if the configuration property hive.support.quoted.identifiers is set to none.

That being said you could create a new table or view using the following:

```
drop table if       exists database.table_name;
create table if not exists database.table_name as
select `(column_to_remove_1|...|column_to_remove_N)?+.+`
    from database.some_table
    where 
    ...
;
```

This will create a table that has all the columns from some_table except the columns named column_to_remove_1, ... , to column_to_remove_N.  You can also choose to create a view instead.

Comment: Can you explain you regex. why you regex end with "+.+" not ".+"

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name REPLACE COLUMNS ( c1 int, c2 String);
```

> NOTE: eliminate column from column list. It will keep matched columns and removed unmentioned columns from table schema.

Answer (score 0):

we can not delete column from hive table . But droping a table(if its external) in hive and the recreating table(with column excluded) ,wont delete ur data .
so what can u do is(if u dont have table structure) run this command  :

```
show create table database_name.table_name;
```

Then you can copy it and edit it (with column eliminated).Afterwards you can do as per invoke the shell

Comment: I don't think this is true.  Dropping a table does delete the data.

Comment: @DashK: i updated answer.On dropping internal table data is deleted but its not the case in external table.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by external table? Is it a table that does not exist in Hive?

Comment: @DashK [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038414/difference-between-hive-internal-tables-and-external-tables] refer this link

Answer (score 0):

table details are empid,name,dept,salary ,address. i want remove address column. Just write REPLACE COLUMNS like below query 
jdbc:hive2://> alter table employee replace columns(empid int, name string,dept string,salary int);

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can't drop table using an alter statement.

Alter - replace is not guaranteed to work in all the cases.

I found the best answer for this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48921280/4385453