# Hive cannot alter partitioned ORC table, replace columns (delete columns)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, orc

Tried to use Hive to replace columns (deleting several columns), used command below, received error message (follows). Table is external, partitioned, ORC,

```
ALTER TABLE D.T REPLACE COLUMNS ( list of columns to keep ) ;
```

Error,

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Replacing columns cannot drop columns for table sandbox6.alc_ont_oe_order_headers_all. SerDe may be incompatible
```

This question suggests that above should work
[Alter hive table add or drop column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198114/alter-hive-table-add-or-drop-column)

And this question also suggests same, but users report similar problem to mine,
[Drop column of hive table stored as orc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068903/drop-column-of-hive-table-stored-as-orc)

Am I doing something wrong, or do I just need to copy to a new table?
*(Hive version is 2.5.3.0)*

Comment: Might it be related to permissions, your user has no privileges to perform that action?

Comment: The error message does not indicate permissions, but that might just be a poor choice of error message. How would I determine which user(s) have the requisite permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045468/which-users-have-hive-table-ddl-schema-manipulation-permissions

Comment: Also not sure if this is user permissions. Try some commands described here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization