# SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to load a text file from HDFS into Hive database using following command

```
hive> load data local inpath '/user/hive/input/emp_details.txt' into table emp;
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/user/hive/input/emp_details.txt'': No files matching path file:/user/hive/input/emp_details.txt

I'm using hive 1.2.2 on hadoop 2.7.2 on Centos7 OS

I gave the full permissions to the file path in HDFS using following command:

```
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/input
```

Not sure what else is missing, could anyone please suggest what to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOCAL keyword means you are trying to load data from local filesystem and not from HDFS.

You should use:

```
load data inpath '/user/hive/input/emp_details.txt' into table emp;
```

See also [Difference between `load data inpath ` and `location` in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35473933/2417043)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. Its loading the data properly now.                                                          hive> load data inpath '/user/hive/input/emp_details.txt' into table emp;
Loading data to table payroll.emp
Table payroll.emp stats: [numFiles=2, numRows=0, totalSize=243, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.883 seconds
hive>