# Difference between external and internal tables performance?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I want to create a table with static data such as country codes and names in HDFS. I will use a csv to load the data into the system. It doesn't matter if I drop the table and the data because this is information you can easily find on the Internet.

Is there any performance consideration about external/internal tables for this type of data? Should I stick with external tables like all the people in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038414/difference-between-hive-internal-tables-and-external-tables) says?

Comment: Performance wise, there should not be a difference. In the post you linked people have pointed out the main difference - when you drop a table, and external table will not remove the data, while an internal table will.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen ODonnell pointed out in the comments, internal/external is really more about the location of the data and what manages it.

I would say there are other important performance factors to consider, for example the table format and whether or not compression is to be used.

The following is from an *HDP* perspective; for *Cloudera* the general concept is the same, but the specifics would probably differ.)

For example, you could define the table as being in [**ORC**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-HiveQLSyntax) Format, which offers many optimizations, such as *predicate pushdown* that allows rows to be optimized out at the storage layer before they are even added into the SQL processing layer. [More details](http://hortonworks.com/blog/orcfile-in-hdp-2-better-compression-better-performance/) on that.

Another option would be whether or not you want to specify compression, such as *Snappy*, a compression algorithm which balances speed and compression ratio (see ORC link above for more info).

Generally speaking, I treat the HDFS data as a source, and *sqoop* it into *Hive* into a **managed** (internal) table with with ORC format and snappy compression enabled. I find that provides good performance with the added benefit that any *ETL* can be done to this data without regard for the original source data in *HDFS*, since it was copied into *Hive* during the *sqoop*.

This does of course require extra space, which may be a consideration depending on your environment and/or specific use case.