# How to create a hive table from another hive table with different partition without moving data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a table database1.table1

Table 'database1.table1' has 2 columns and one partition column: columnA, columnB partitioned by columnC

I need to create a table 'database2.table2' with no partition but with two columns columnA, columnB. I need to COPY the data from database1.table1 into database2.table2 (without deleting any data in database1.table1)

I tried the following but the data gets moved. I need to just copy the data

```
CREATE TABLE DATABASE2.TABLE2 
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1
```

Note: I need the table with actual data and I can not create an EXTERNAL table.

Comment: An external table "has data". I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that point

Comment: I believe external table are more like database views which does not store any actual data

Comment: No, external tables do contain data. The only thing that external tables differ in is whether their data is deleted from disk when you drop a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038414/difference-between-hive-internal-tables-and-external-tables

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy the data almost the way you were saying. Just add 'AS'. See [the CREATE AS SELECT documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)).
You're saying that the data is moved, but that can't be.
CREATE AS SELECT will trigger a map reduce job. Notice in the docs
that you can also change the data format, use a different serde, and
your own partitioning (or no partitioning, like you're asking).

```
USE database2;
CREATE TABLE table2 
  AS SELECT columna,columnb 
  FROM database1.table1
```

Comment: My mistake. The source table content was deleted by some other process. This happened immediately after I have applied the create command by coincidence.