# Difference of performance between internal table and extenal table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to do some actions to files on hdfs by using hive temporarily,so i do not want to use internal table.but my data is so huge ,for example 1TB,so I worry about the performance of external table.
so I ask the question about
difference of performance between table and extenal table in hive.

Comment: Hope you are looking for difference between Internal table and external table in Hive. Please clarify.

Comment: yes，I got the wrong word "extend".I'm sorry.I search again by using the right word,and get some answer,which is no difference of performance between them.it isn't right?

Comment: Refer this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37192041/2142994

Comment: Yes. there is no major difference in performance between both table types. But here you have  large data size and  you are using hive temporarily then you should use internal table.

Comment: why should I use internal table,when my data is large,if there's no difference between them?

Comment: finally, I think there's no difference of performance between them, the only difference between them is when you drop the table, you will drop your data with using internal table, too. which means if you want to do it both, you use internal table for less work. and if you intend to pursue the performance, you might use ORC table which mentioned by @Ani Menon

Answer (score 0):

You may just create hive external tables and use them. I haven't noticed any major difference in performance internal and external tables.

To improve performance you may create ORC(file format) tables which are managed by hive.

```
Create ORC table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <orc_table_name>(
    <col name> <type>)
COMMENT 'comments'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS ORC;
```

Then insert into ORC tables:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <orc_table_name> SELECT * FROM <external_table_name>;
```

Refer: [HDFS to Hive external table and ORC](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_dataintegration/content/moving_data_from_hdfs_to_hive_external_table_method.html)

Answer (score 0):

Difference between external and internal table performance that i have experienced is

internal tables takes more CPU Time

External tables takes less CPU Time by approximately 40%