# Skip first line of csv while loading in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

**Hello Friends,**

I created table in hive with help of following command -

```
CREATE TABLE db.test 
  ( 
     fname STRING, 
     lname STRING, 
     age   STRING, 
     mob   BIGINT 
  ) row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' stored AS textfile;
```

Now to load data in table from file, I am using following command -

```
load data local inpath '/home/cluster/TestHive.csv' into table db.test;
```

Problem is, all the rows are getting inserted, and I don't want first row because it contains only column names.

Please suggest me a way to skip first line.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row/15753145#15753145

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hive External table-CSV File- Header row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457267/hive-external-table-csv-file-header-row)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip CSV header in Hive External Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/how-to-skip-csv-header-in-hive-external-table)

Answer (score 56):

To get this you can use hive's property which is **TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")** 
**you can also refer example -**

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
  ( 
     name STRING, 
     id   INT 
  ) 
row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' lines terminated BY '\n' 
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: Working on Hive, but not on Impala.

Comment: have you created table in Hive and accessing from Impala?

Comment: No, I used the `CREATE TABLE` statement with that `tblproperty` directly on Impala shell. I did not try the statement in Hive and then access the same table from Impala.

Answer (score 11):

Just for those who have already created the table with the header. Here is the alter command for the same.

`ALTER TABLE tablename SET TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");`

Answer (score 3):

Just don't mix double quotes and single quotes in the same CLI command:

```
CREATE TABLE db.test 
  ( 
     fname STRING, 
     lname STRING, 
     age   STRING, 
     mob   BIGINT 
  ) row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' tblproperties('skip.header.line.count'='1') stored AS textfile;
```

otherwise hive load `NULL` values.