# Hive - How to remove column header from result set

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to fix one issue which has created after hive query execution.

A new table named 'stock_data' which is holding stock price , stock symbol and all other details.

I had a tsv file ( tab separated file ) and used 'load data local inpath' command to load database table.

tsv file having column  header like 'stock_name','stock_symbol' ....

Now, when I wanted to display stock symbol and with number of counts using below query :-

```
select stock_symbol,count(*) from stocks group by stock_symbol;
```

Output is loading column header

```
XOM 500
XRX 500
XTO 496
YPF 500
YUM 500
YZC 478
ZAP 494
ZF  494
stock_symbol    1

Time taken: 20.576 seconds, Fetched: 1735 row(s)
```

My question is :-

How to hide or remove 'stock_symbol 1' ( Last line ) from my result set ?

I tried to use below command before run :-

```
set hive.cli.print.header=false;
```

Did not work for me ...

Could anyone help me for the same ..

Thanks ..

Comment: You cna use a where condition.

Answer (score 1):

try below command from shell terminal

> hive -s -e 'select stock_symbol,count(*) from stocks group by stock_symbol;' | tail -1

Note:use tail or head commands to terminate the last line...

Comment: Thanks men, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would appear to be that your data was imported with the header as a data row.  I might suggest that you just delete the value:

```
delete from stocks
    where stock_symbol = 'stock_symbol';
```

Otherwise, you can modify your queries and use `WHERE` to exclude it:

```
select stock_symbol, count(*)
from stocks
where stock_symbol <> 'stock_symbol'
group by stock_symbol;
```

Answer (score 0):

belive you are having the Input Dump which all having header, and thats what its reflecting in the count.

Please check the link
[Skip first line of csv while loading in hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813355/skip-first-line-of-csv-while-loading-in-hive-table)

the answer has been shared already :)

sample example meantion earlier also

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
  ( 
     name STRING, 
     id   INT 
  ) row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' lines terminated BY '\n' 
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Comment: yes you are right ..During insertion , header exist  inside tsv file. Now I was trying to run query without showing header in output.