# noob to Hadoop, uploaded a tab-delimited txt file with column headers how do I make use of it in Hive?

Tags: excel, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I’ve uploaded a excel file that is now tab-delimited txt file with column headers how do I make use of it in Hadoop Pig & hive for normal table functions? do i have to reupload without column headers so it can be recognised as a table?

https://ibb.co/jqwK6k

Comment: Did you *search* a little bit?? You would have found posts like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813355/skip-first-line-of-csv-while-loading-in-hive-table

Answer (score 0):

No need to reupload ,You can remove headers in pig and hive. to remove in pig use RANK function ,and filter where rank!=1 ,for hive refer below link. http://bigdataprogrammers.com/remove-header-of-csv-file-in-hive/
Note: use \t as delimiter instead of comma.