# Insert values from file to an existing table on hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyhive

I am new to hadoop ecosystem. I was trying to create hive table from CSV file using the below query.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proxy_data(
  date_time TIMESTAMP,time_taken INT, c_ip STRING,
  sc_status INT, s_action STRING, sc_bytes INT,
  cs_bytes INT, cs_method STRING, cs_uri STRING,
  cs_host STRING, uri_port INT, uri_path STRING,
  uri_query STRING, username STRING, auth STRING,
  supplier_name STRING, content_type STRING, referer STRING,
  user_agent STRING, filter_result STRING, categories STRING,
  x_virus_id STRING, proxy_ip STRING
)
COMMENT 'Proxy logs' 
LOCATION '/user/admin'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

This query actually created a table proxy_data and populated the values present in the csv files which are located in the prescribed location.

Now, I want to append values from another set of CSVs to the same table(it should skip the headings present in the csv file). I checked for various solutions, but nothing is meeting my need.

Comment: What about just _moving_ the new files to the existing directory? Or creating a partitioned table, and adding a new directory (= partition with arbitrary key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may follow this approach:

1. Create a staging table (temporary table) with this property - skip.header.line.count=1
2. Create a main table with same schema (no need to use `skip.header.line.count` clause in this table).
3. Every time you have a new file, load overwrite into the staging table
4. Then, load append staging table's data into the main table.

   ```
   create table <my_table_stg>(col1 data_type1, col2, data_type2...)
   row format delimited fields terminated by ','
   tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

   create table <my_table>(col1 data_type1, col2, data_type2...);

   load data inpath '/file/location/my_file.csv' overwrite into table <my_table_stg>;

   insert into table <my_table> select * from <my_table_stg>;
   ```

P.S: Your table syntax doesn't have`row format delimited` clause. Please make sure you add it as shown above

Comment: This sort of helped. I was able to create a temporary table to which I populated the data overwriting each time and later on selected the data from the temporary data and inserted into my existing table. And like you mentioned I added "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " line to the code and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property to your table which will skip the first row of csv. 
"skip.header.line.count"="1"

In your case,

```
Alter Table proxy_data SET TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1").
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
hive>  LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/yourcsvfile.csv' INTO TABLE proxy_data;
```

Comment: What about the header row?

Comment: @Ben Watson I think it's gonna just retrieve values from CSV

Comment: As OP says, "it should skip the headings present in the csv file". This answer won't do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813355/skip-first-line-of-csv-while-loading-in-hive-table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row/15753145#15753145

Comment: When I use this, it is not appending, it is overwriting the old data with the new one.