# Reading CSV with Column header and loading it in hive tables

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, cloudera

I have csv file with column header inside the file.
e.g.

Column1 Column2 Column3
value1   value2  value 3
value1   value2  value 3
value1  value2  value 3
value1  value2  value 3

Now i want to create hive table using this header inside and then load the entire table without the header line into the table. 
Can anyone please suggest what approach should be followed in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hive External table-CSV File- Header row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457267/hive-external-table-csv-file-header-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify

```
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

see this SO question [(Hive External table-CSV File- Header row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457267/hive-external-table-csv-file-header-row)

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the header line before loading data into HDFS, no other options here.