# Removing header while creating external over a directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a csv file which is in a HDFS directory.
Problem here is my file is having header.
When i am creating external table on it, I am getting this headers as a row.
How can i remove this header in `HDFS itself` while creating external table.
I know a way by doing insert overwrite after creating table leaving the first row.
Is their any other way of doing this. Please help me.

Comment: It is not possible to do with out intermediate process..

Check this post..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row

Comment: Thanks for the link Venkatesh. Was wondering how to achieve this.