# Skip first row from Hive external table in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr

I have following data:

```
 "ElemUID   ElemName    Kind    Number  DaySecFrom(UTC) DaySecTo(UTC)"
"399126817  A648/13FKO-66   DEZ     2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"483492732  A661/18FRS-97   DEZ   120.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"399126819  A648/12FKO-2    DEZ    60.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"399126818  A648/12FKO-1    DEZ   180.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"399126816  A648/13FKO-65   DEZ     2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"398331142  A661/31OFN-1    DEZ   120.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"398331143  A661/31OFN-2    DEZ     2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"483492739  A5/28FKN-65 DEZ     2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"483492735  A661/23FRS-97   DEZ    60.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
"483492740  B44/104FSN-33   DEZ   180.00    2017-07-01 23:58:00.000 2017-07-01 23:59:00.000"
```

I loaded it to HDFS. Then I defined a external table in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deg
(
ElemUID int,
ElemName string,
Kind string,
Number float,
timefromdeg string,
timetodeg string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Then I loaded the dataset into the defined schema with `LOAD DATA INPATH..`
Now I want it to load it with `tbl()` to sparklyr. Everytime I do this I allways get the header as data in the first row:
Output of `glimpse()`:

```
Variables: 6
$ elemuid  <int> NA, 399126817, 483492732, 399126819, 399126818, 399126816, 39...
$ elemname <chr> "ElemName", "A648/13FKO-66", "A661/18FRS-97", "A648/12FKO-2",...
$ kind     <chr> "Kind", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ", "DEZ...
$ number   <dbl> NaN, NaN, 120, 60, 180, NaN, 120, NaN, NaN, 60, 180, NaN, NaN...
$ timefrom <dttm> NA, 2017-07-01 23:58:00, 2017-07-01 23:58:00, 2017-07-01 23:...
$ timeto   <dttm> NA, 2017-07-01 23:59:00, 2017-07-01 23:59:00, 2017-07-01 23:...
```

I feel like this disturbs my later analysis. At create external `table()` I already used `TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")`

Is there a possibility to skip the first row in sparklyr?

Thank you!

Comment: the first row is mostly empty except for elemenname and kind.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: i think elemname and kind is not NA because these columns have a reproduceable format (char)

Comment: Please include example data and table definition.

Comment: Don't think this is a sparklyr issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751999/hive-external-table-skip-first-row